# Aspnet Core with Adfs 2016 OpenId can't sign out

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, adfs, .net-core-rc2

I setup an MVC project with Aspnet Core targeting Net461. Authentication is configured to use Adfs from a Windows Server 2016 system.  I managed to get sign in working, however, when I click sign out I am given a page cannot be displayed error. Browsing back to the home url shows that the user is still logged in also. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible related post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37338147/6279711

Comment: I don't believe sign-out is implemented yet.

Comment: I believe it has to do with the lack of a tenantid being known when using adfs. Without that I'm not sure that it knows how to log out. Not sure how to fix that though or if it's possible yet.

Comment: What is the URL of the page with the error "cannot be displayed"?

Comment: Ill pay a screenshot later but it is the url of the sign out action in the account controller. The message displayed mentions whatever url I use for the postredirecturl and says there were too many redirects. Network traffic in come developed tools show the signout url being called over and over until the redirect error happens.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this sample useful (even though it is for Azure ADFS, it works for local installs as well): https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore

The logout action method like the following work well in my case:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SignOut()
{
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(SignedOut), "Account", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
    return SignOut(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

This will redirect you to the `/Account/SignedOut` after it completes and you need to register your `/signout-callback-oidc` endpoint for your client as well. This endpoint is used (by default) by the OIDC ASP.NET Core middleware.